# wordpress website, using cloudflare as CDN, CSS on the live site keeps disappearing and sometime css classes does not work when i inspect the element

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, cloudflare

I am working on a wordpress website, using cloudflare CDN. I have dev, staging and live site, where dev and staging works perfectly fine but live site works very weird, CSS on the site keeps disappearing and sometimes css classes from product pages does not work or disappear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If as you say "dev and staging works perfectly fine" and "CSS on the site keeps disappearing" (implying that the CSS styling is visible sometimes) then it's possible there's a server issue _ If this is the case you'll probably get more assistance from your webhost support

Comment: Do you use some caching plugin ? A chrome extension that reloads css ?? Lots of things can happen depending on server or your browser   ......

Comment: thanks for your quck response, i just realised, my divi css in not loading on live site, let me contact my host as well'

Comment: yes i do use cloudflare, wp-rocket and asset clean-up on my site, i have cleared all cache as well

Comment: Divi can be tricky, esp if you're relying on the Theme Customizer to make CSS changes. Usually, problems will clear up if you re-save in Divi Options.